# Old 261 MB PATA Hard Disk Shows Up in Gnome-Disks as 2.2 TB

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive, partitioning, pata

I am trying to check an old 261 MB Hard disk before disposal.

`SEAGATE ST3290A 
    * 1001 CYL 
    * 15 HEADS 
    * 34 SECT 
    * 261.3 MB`

I'm using NewerTech ATA to USB Adapter and connecting to a laptop running Ubuntu 16.04. So, in *gnome-disks*, the drive is showing up as a 2.2 TB drive, so obviously something isn't understanding the drive parameters properly. Any ideas of things I could try (in fdisk, maybe?) to recognize the drive properly, or is it just too old for contemporary equipment to read?

Comment: Ditch the USB adapter and plug it in directly.  Either the adapter is confused or the drive is broken ( or both ).

Comment: It's a modern laptop, it doesn't have a PATA interface on it.

Comment: Obviously you will need to find a computer that does have a PATA interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use GPartEd on that disk and check how GParted sees the disk-layout.
If the first parition(s) look OK (e.g. less than 261 MB in size) and there is bogus trash after that on the disk simple delete the bogus partitions. GParted should then save a corrected version of the partition-table which will fix the problem.

If GParted can't make sense of it either

- the USB adapter is the culprit, try with another one or a computer that has a real PATA interface.
- the disk is broken and reports trash information or
- the disk has a non-standard partitioning scheme which is unreadable without the original computer that created that partitioning scheme

In the last 2 cases there is nothing you can do. Expect take the drive apart and re-use the platters as coasters for your drinks.

!!! Something I just remembered: Make sure you have the PATA drive jumpered as "MASTER in a single-drive configuration". Most USB-PATA converters require this in order to be able to reliably read the drive, but it isn't mentioned anywhere in the manual in most cases.

Comment: D'oh! I suppose if the jumper hadn't been on the _bottom_ of the disk I'd have remembered that. Anyway, yeah, turns out that GParted can't see it, and the USB adapter works with all the other PATA drives I've tried today, so the disk is fried. Thanks!